# jQuery Expand And Scroll Down

Tags: jquery

I want to expand section on click and scroll down after. 
My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $(".cp_view_more_details" ).click(function() {
    $('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000', function(){
      $( ".cp_expanded_view" ).scrollTop( 300 );
    });
  });
});
```

It expand section, but not scrolls down. 
I don't have any errors in my console.

How can I make it scroll down?

Comment: Please post your `html` too..

Answer (score 1):

not fully sure though, I think you should use the window instead of the wrapper class

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $(".cp_expanded_view").hide();
     $( ".cp_view_more_details" ).click(function() {
        $('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000', function(){
                $(window).scrollTop( 300 );
           });
        });
   });
```

See this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xc27avjL/6/

With simple animation. you may use the body or html

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $(".cp_expanded_view").hide();
     $( ".cp_view_more_details" ).click(function() {
        $('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000', function(){
                $('html,body').animate(
            {scrollTop :  300
            }, 'slow');
           });
        });
   });
```

fiddle  here : http://jsfiddle.net/xc27avjL/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $(".cp_view_more_details" ).click(function() {
    $('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000', function(){
      var height = $(document).height();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: height  }, 300 );
    });
  });
});
```

i used a variable for the document height and then used `animate scrollTop`